# Changing a value of an observation conditional to the value of the next observation by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of trips by person (`trips_data`). Each observation is a trip with the start time of the trip (`strttime`), the end time of the trip (`endtime`) and the person who does the trip. For some person, the endtime a trip is later than the start of the next trip. Here is an example with the time in format hhmm :

```
       TRIPID clepersonne  strttime  endtime
90  100010413    10001041      1600     1614
91  100010414    10001041      1615     1648
92  100010415    10001041      1645     1726
93  100010416    10001041      1930     1954
94  100010621    10001062       900      921
95  100010622    10001062      1000     1013
```

The `TRIPID` `100010414` terminate later than the `strttime` of the next trip `100010415` for the same personne `10001041`. I would like to correct this inconsistency by replacind the `endtime` of the trip `100010414` by the start time of the next trip. For this example, the result that I want is:

```
       TRIPID clepersonne  strttime  endtime
90  100010413    10001041      1600     1614
91  100010414    10001041      1615     *1645*
92  100010415    10001041      1645     1726
93  100010416    10001041      1930     1954
94  100010621    10001062       900      921
95  100010622    10001062      1000     1013
```

I have tried doing this :

```
    trips_data = trips_data.sort_index() # To iterate each value
    for i in range(0, len(trips_data.index)) :
        trips_data['endtime'] = np.where((trips_data.strttime[i+1]<trips_data.endtime[i]) & (trips_data.clepersonne[i+1] == trips_data.clepersonne[i]), trips_data.strttime[i+1], trips_data['endtime'] )
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-23-64092a4318fd>", line 3, in <module>
    trips_data['endtime'] = np.where((trips_data.strttime[i+1]<trips_data.endtime[i]) & (trips_data.clepersonne[i+1] == trips_data.clepersonne[i]), trips_data.strttime[i+1], trips_data['endtime'] )
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 122
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
next_start=df.groupby('clepersonne')['strttime'].shift(-1)
mask=df['endtime'].sub(next_start)>0
df['endtime']=df['endtime'].mask(mask,next_start)
print(df)

       TRIPID  clepersonne  strttime  endtime
90  100010413     10001041      1600     1614
91  100010414     10001041      1615     1645
92  100010415     10001041      1645     1726
93  100010416     10001041      1930     1954
94  100010621     10001062       900      921
95  100010622     10001062      1000     1013
```

Comment: I am glad to help you!:)